# How to apply custom css to react-d3-speedometer

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-d3-speedometer

I am trying to achieve something like this, with the help of react-d3-speedometer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24IcP.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in `react-d3-speedometer` at the time of this writing. There is an open issue tracking this here - https://github.com/palerdot/react-d3-speedometer/issues/92